# Does Cloud Firestore support React Native

Tags: database, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I currently use Firebase real-time database for my react-native mobile apps and I have been looking for some alternatives that provide better querying capabilities. One of the strong points for Firestore is its querying capabilities. I wanted to check if Firestore supports React Native out of the box.

Comment: Did you look t the Firestore docs?

Comment: I did and it is not mentioned explicitly if it supports or doesn't support React Native.

Comment: did you find anything? I'm looking a way to make react native app with mobx and firestore

Comment: I use react-native-firebase as suggested in the accepted answer.

Comment: you can use firestore also? it's the same?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Oct 3rd release of [React Native Firebase](https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase/releases/tag/v3.0.0) includes Cloud Firestore support.

> First pass at support for the newly release Cloud Firestore beta, see
>   http://invertase.link/firestore for supported api's.

```
import firebase from 'react-native-firebase';

firebase.firestore()
  .collection('posts')
  .add({
    title: 'Amazing post',
  })
  .then(() => {
    // Document added to collection and ID generated
    // Will have path: `posts/{generatedId}`
  })
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I currently use the Firebase web SDK in my react native app but I guess the web SDK for Firestore doesn't currently support React Native.

Answer (score 1):

Cloud firestore supports multiple framework listed here:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/library-integrations

Answer (score 0):

Additionally, you can use a library like Firestorter to hook your firestore data directly to your React components:

https://github.com/IjzerenHein/firestorter

https://medium.com/@hrutjes/building-a-react-firestore-app-with-zero-effort-and-mobx-525df611eabf

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this framework from invertase ; 
https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v3.3.x/getting-started